# Moneris Recurring Payment Gateway on Laravel 5.4

Tags: api

I have gone through the Moneris documentation, they have given straightforward API. I am trying to do recurring payment but not able to understand how to get DataKeys of previously made transition of the particular customer. Here what I have written for the purchase in which DateKey is used as a static from the demo Moneris Payment documentation. But I am not able to get my client data_key, how can we get that dataKey please help me out! If this code is not good let me know the better solution.

/************************ Transaction Variables ******************************/

```
    $data_key='FjhVlt4020HAVSaOmnaaPACpJ';
    $orderid='ord-'.date("dmy-G:i:s");
    $amount='1.00';
    $custid='test';
    $crypt_type='1';
    $commcard_invoice='Invoice 123';
    $commcard_tax_amount='1.00';

    /************************** CVD Variables *****************************/

    $cvd_indicator = '1';
    $cvd_value = '198';

    /********************** CVD Associative Array *************************/

    $cvdTemplate = array(
                         'cvd_indicator' => $cvd_indicator,
                         'cvd_value' => $cvd_value
                        );

    $mpgCvdInfo = new mpgCvdInfo ($cvdTemplate);

    /************************** Recur Variables *****************************/

    $recurUnit = 'day';
    $startDate = '2018/04/09';
    $numRecurs = '4';
    $recurInterval = '10';
    $recurAmount = '09.00';
    $startNow = 'true';

    /****************************** Recur Array **************************/

    $recurArray = array('recur_unit'=>$recurUnit,  // (day | week | month)
                        'start_date'=>$startDate, //yyyy/mm/dd
                        'num_recurs'=>$numRecurs,
                        'start_now'=>$startNow,
                        'period' => $recurInterval,
                        'recur_amount'=> $recurAmount
                        );

    $mpgRecur = new mpgRecur($recurArray);

    /************************ Transaction Array **********************************/

    $txnArray=array('type'=>'res_purchase_cc',  
                    'data_key'=>$data_key,
                    'order_id'=>$orderid,
                    'cust_id'=>$custid,
                    'amount'=>$amount,
                    'crypt_type'=>$crypt_type,
                    'commcard_invoice'=>$commcard_invoice,
                    'commcard_tax_amount'=>$commcard_tax_amount
                     );

    /************************ Transaction Object *******************************/

    $mpgTxn = new mpgTransaction($txnArray);
    $mpgTxn->setCvdInfo($mpgCvdInfo);
    $mpgTxn->setRecur($mpgRecur);

    /************************ Request Object **********************************/

    $mpgRequest = new mpgRequest($mpgTxn);
    $mpgRequest->setProcCountryCode("US"); //"CA" for sending transaction to Canadian environment
    $mpgRequest->setTestMode(true); //false or comment out this line for production transactions

    /************************ mpgHttpsPost Object ******************************/

    $mpgHttpPost  =new mpgHttpsPost($store_id,$api_token,$mpgRequest);

    /************************ Response Object **********************************/

    $mpgResponse=$mpgHttpPost->getMpgResponse();
    // print_r($mpgResponse);
    print("\nDataKey = " . $mpgResponse->getDataKey());
    print("\nReceiptId = " . $mpgResponse->getReceiptId());
    print("\nReferenceNum = " . $mpgResponse->getReferenceNum());
    print("\nResponseCode = " . $mpgResponse->getResponseCode());
    print("\nAuthCode = " . $mpgResponse->getAuthCode());
    print("\nMessage = " . $mpgResponse->getMessage());
    print("\nTransDate = " . $mpgResponse->getTransDate());
    print("\nTransTime = " . $mpgResponse->getTransTime());
    print("\nTransType = " . $mpgResponse->getTransType());
    print("\nComplete = " . $mpgResponse->getComplete());
    print("\nTransAmount = " . $mpgResponse->getTransAmount());
    print("\nCardType = " . $mpgResponse->getCardType());
    print("\nTxnNumber = " . $mpgResponse->getTxnNumber());
    print("\nTimedOut = " . $mpgResponse->getTimedOut());
    print("\nAVSResponse = " . $mpgResponse->getAvsResultCode());
    print("\nRecurSuccess = " . $mpgResponse->getRecurSuccess());
    print("\nResSuccess = " . $mpgResponse->getResSuccess());
    print("\nPaymentType = " . $mpgResponse->getPaymentType());

    //----------------- ResolveData ------------------------------

    print("\n\nCust ID = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataCustId());
    print("\nPhone = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataPhone());
    print("\nEmail = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataEmail());
    print("\nNote = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataNote());
    print("\nMasked Pan = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataMaskedPan());
    print("\nExp Date = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataExpDate());
    print("\nCrypt Type = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataCryptType());
    print("\nAvs Street Number = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataAvsStreetNumber());
    print("\nAvs Street Name = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataAvsStreetName());
    print("\nAvs Zipcode = " . $mpgResponse->getResDataAvsZipcode());
```

Comment: I got the solution, we need to setup vault credit card profile. Here is the link https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/API/Vault?lang=php.

Answer (score 0):

I have mailed to MINDBODY API support, they responded with the message

"Due to current API limitations, there is not a current option to filter the GetClasses REQUEST by the time. It would currently be necessary to parse the RESPONSE for the desired times."

There is no filter option with time.

Thank you